# What is the formula for calculating interest from comms?

Tags: ibomber-defense

What is the formula for income from comms in iBomber Defense and iBomber Defense Pacific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Pacific gameplay (but I believe the numbers are the same for the earlier game):

- In Pacific, you only get interest if you have the interest specialization
- Each level 1 comm provides 3.33%
- Each level 2 comm provides 6.66%
- Each level 3 comm provides 10%
- Values are cumulative, so having one level 1 comm, one level 2 comm and one level 3 comms will result in `3.33+6.66+10 = 20%` interest rate
- Interest is hard-capped to 60$ per turn

Comment: I was just playing iBomber Defense today and it appears that the interest cap is $50